# Intel C++ compiler (icpc 14.0): "a derived class is not allowed here"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, language-lawyer, icc

I'm using ICC 14.0.2 on Linux. This code snippet compiles with GCC and CLang, but not ICC:

```
template<int N, bool B>
struct A;

template<int N>
struct A<N,false>
{
  template<int M>
  struct Nested {};
};

template<int N>
struct A<N,true> : public A<N,false> {};

template struct A<1,true>::Nested<2>;    // explicit instantiation
```

Trying to compile this with the three compilers:

```
$ g++ -c -std=c++11 testcase.cc
$ clang++ -c -std=c++11 testcase.cc
$ icpc -c -std=c++11 testcase.cc
testcase.cc(17): error: invalid qualifier for "A<1, false>::Nested<2>" (a derived class is not allowed here)
  template struct A<1,true>::Nested<2>;
                             ^

compilation aborted for testcase.cc (code 2)
```

I couldn't find any useful information about this error message.

In my case, the explicit instantiation (of more complicated classes) is part of a unit test, and I can work around the problem by instantiating an object instead, which ICC happily compiles:

```
void foo()
{
  A<1,true>::Nested<2>();
}
```

Still I would like to now if ICC is right with its error or whether this is a compiler bug.

Thanks for your time!

**Update**
Thank you Filip for the detailed analysis. [I reported](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/507581) the issue to the Intel developers. Indeed the partial specialization has nothing to do with the problem (as I initially suspected), so even this simpler snippet reproduces the problem:

```
template<int N>
struct A
{
  template<int M>
  struct Nested {};
};

template<int N>
struct B : public A<N> {};

template struct B<1>::Nested<2>;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>**Note:** `gcc` and `clang` are showing the correct behavior...</sup>

---

**THE BUG IS IN `icc`!**

The snippet accepted by both *gcc* and *clang* is legal and should not trigger a diagnostic.

---

The author responsible for the code inside `icc` that issues the provided diagnostic did probably trip over the below snippet, taken from the Standard, which says that names in a `Base` that depends on a *template-parameter* should not be available inside the definition of the `Derived` class.

> 14.6.2 **Dependent Names** `[temp.dep]`
>
> > <sup>3</sup>  **In the definition of a class or class template, if a base class depends on a
> >     *template-parameter*, the base class scope is not examined** during
> >     unqualified name lookup either at the point of definition of the class
> >     template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or
> >     member.

---

As stated it is important to note that `[temp.dep]p3` says that the *base class scope is not examined in the **definition** of a class*, it doesn't say that such names are not inherited when being accessed from the outside.

Your "work around" shows that the name (in this case `template<int> struct Nested`) is indeed (correctly) inherited and available inside `A<1, true>`, but `icc` seems to confuse *explicit instantiation* with the rules of names inside the *definition of the class*.

Comment: Can someone please enlighten me with a reason for the downvote?

Comment: It's probably from that particular developer of `icc` ;)